# How to create the correct return type?

Tags: java, generics, types, extends, mismatch

I will post my question at the bottom.

Below is the class that other classes extend from.

```
public class people {

    class family extends people {   
    }

    class friends extends people {  
    }

    class coworkers extends people {    
    }
}
```

Below is the class that has the method getAllPeopleByClass that gets invoked by the getMembers() method in the selection classes:

```
public class processing {

static processing process = null;
private Collection<family> familyList = new ArrayList<family>();
private Collection<coworkers> cowList = new ArrayList<coworkers>();
private Collection<friends> friendList = new ArrayList<friends>();

public processing(){
}

public static processing getInstance() {
    if (process == null)
        process = new processing();
    return process;
}

public <T> Collection<people> getAllPeopleByClass(Class<T> clazz) {
    Collection<people> peopleCollection;
    peopleCollection.addAll(getList(clazz));
    return peopleCollection;
}

private <T> Collection<? extends people> getList(Class<T> clazz) {
    if (clazz == family.class) {  
        return familyList;  
    } else if (clazz == coworkers.class) {
        return cowList;
    } else { // else if clazz == friends.class
        return friendList;
    }
}
```

And finally, the classes that use processing:

```
 public class familySelection {
  public Collection<family> getMembers() {
    Collection<family> f;
    f = processing.getInstance().getAllPeopleByClass(family.class); //type mismatch
    return f; 
  }
}

 public class coworkerSelection {
  public Collection<coworkers> getMembers() {
    Collection<coworkers> c;
    c = processing.getInstance().getAllPeopleByClass(coworkers.class); //type mismatch
    return c;
  }
}


public class friendsSelection {
  public Collection<friends> getMembers() {
    Collection<friends> f;
    f = processing.getInstance().getAllPeopleByClass(friends.class); //type mismatch
    return f;
  }
}
```

My problem is that I get type mismatch from the getAllPeopleByClass call in each of my getMembers() methods.

I have tried this:

```
public class familySelection {
  public Collection<family> getMembers() {
    Collection<? extends people> f; //changed to extend from people
    f = processing.getInstance().getAllPeopleByClass(family.class);
    return (Collection<family>) f; //cast warning - dont want that
  }
}
```

This works, but I get a cast warning, which I don't want and I don't want to suppress it.  This is the closest I have come to fixing the problem. Also, the return type of getMembers() must remain as is.  Does anyone have a way to do this without any warnings?  Or even somehow handle this generically?  Thanks!

Comment: The main issue in your design is that generics are for compile time type enforcement, but you are performing the type checking at runtime. Perhaps consider having 3 separate methods for returning each type of collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public <T> Collection<T> getAllPeopleByClass(Class<T> clazz) {
    Collection<T> peopleCollection = new ArrayList<T>();
    for(people p : getList(clazz)) {
      peopleCollection.add(clazz.cast(p));
    }
    return peopleCollection;
}
```

Comment: Do you even read: This works, but I get a cast warning, which I don't want and I don't want to suppress it.

Comment: @darijan - did you read my (updated) answer fully?  "due to the limits of java generics...".  this is the "most correct" it can be.

Comment: This is a limitation of generics issue?

Comment: @StephenD - yes, there is no way for the compiler to guarantee that the collection returned has the actual typed classes within it.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this without generics?  No code necessary, but if so, it would be nice to know!

Comment: @StephenD - i've added a fully type-safe version.  I didn't realize you were willing to copy the underlying collection.  in this case, you can make it "correct".

Answer (score 1):

Use the `super` keyword:

```
public class familySelection {
  public Collection<? super family> getMembers() {
    Collection<? super family> f;
    f = processing.getInstance().getAllPeopleByClass(family.class);
    return f;
  }
}
```

**UPD:** Use an`super` wildcard, when you only `put` values into a structure. Use an`extends` wildcard , when you only `get` values out of a structure. And don't use wildcards when you use both `get` and `put`.

Comment: this will compile, but it won't be very useful.  having a collection of some type which is a superclass of family is not any more useful than just not using generics at all.

Comment: OP did say the return type of getMembers() must remain as is

Answer (score 0):

I would choose this version. It also require warning suppression but I think this is better place to do that.

I also allowed myself to change your Singleton implementation. If you really want to do it consider using enum.

```
public enum processing {
    INSTANCE;

    private Collection<family> familyList = new ArrayList<family>();
    private Collection<coworkers> cowList = new ArrayList<coworkers>();
    private Collection<friends> friendList = new ArrayList<friends>();

    public static processing getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public <T extends people> Collection<T> getAllPeopleByClass(Class<T> clazz) {
        Collection<T> peopleCollection = new ArrayList<T>();
        peopleCollection.addAll(getList(clazz));
        return peopleCollection;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private <T extends people> Collection<T> getList(Class<T> clazz) {
        if (clazz == family.class) {
            return (Collection<T>) familyList;
        } else if (clazz == coworkers.class) {
            return (Collection<T>) cowList;
        } else { // else if clazz == friends.class
            return (Collection<T>) friendList;
        }
    }
}
```

And familySelection:

```
public class familySelection {
    public Collection<family> getMembers() {
        Collection<family> f = processing.getInstance().getAllPeopleByClass(family.class);
        return f;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your post.  Why do you prefer having warnings when they can be eliminated alltogether?

Comment: I started writing my response before @jtahlborn edited his version.

Comment: And one more thing: Probably in most cases it's not important but he have to execute cast(p) method for each object in collection. And he can do that without risking ClassCastException only because he knows implementation of getList(clazz) method. So he also is doing unchecked cast, it's just not so obvious - and you don't have to suppress it.

Comment: And another thing :) : last "else if" from getList(clazz) should be uncommented. I would not trust that every time someone add new implementation of people he will remember to add new collection to processing class.